# Why does setTimeout execute function without delay?

Tags: javascript, callback, delay

I have wrote following code:

```
// callback function
function tryMe (param1) { 
    alert (param1 ); 
} 

// callback executer 
function callbackTester (callback) { 
    callback(); 
} 

// test function
    callbackTester (  function() {
        setTimeout(  tryMe(1), 10000);
     })
```

I see alert at once after script execution.

Expected result - see alert with delay 10 seconds.

Where do I wrong?

How to correct this code?

Comment: you should invoke the `callbackTester` function in your `setTimeout`, and the `callbackTester` function should invoke the `tryMe` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do that:

```
setTimeout(function() { tryMe(1) }, 10000);
```

In this case the `tryMe(1)` function will be invoked after the specified interval. In your example you were immediately invoking the function.

Basically the `setTimeout` function takes a function pointer as first parameter whereas you passed `tryMe(1)` as first parameter which is the result of the execution of this function.